# ActiveRecord relationships not returning child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm quite new in Ruby and i'm having such an issue with it:

I have defined four models, as listed:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :albums
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tracks
   has_many :covers
   belongs_to :artist
end

class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end
```

When i enter the rails console, i'm able to query for all classes but, when i query for an artist, i.e

```
a = Artist.find(1)
```

i get the following

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Artist.find(1)
   Artist Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `artists`.* FROM `artists`  WHERE `artists`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   => #<Artist id: 1, name: "Sound Storm", genre: "Rock", country: "Italy">
```

I thought, when i query for an artist, it supposed to bring all the albums based on the defined relationship... am i wrong?

Comment: irb(main):007:0> a = Artist.find(1)
  Artist Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  `artists`.* FROM `artists`  WHERE `artists`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<Artist id: 1, name: "Sound Storm", genre: "Rock", country: "Italy">

Comment: irb(main):008:0> a.albums
NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for "Album":String

Answer (score 1):

Rails (not Ruby) uses lazy loading. So it won't do the query on the albums until you ask for it. So after doing `a = Artist.find(1)`, try `a.albums`. It works this way since you don't always want the overhead of hauling in all the associations when you might just want something in the main record.

And when you do `a.albums`, even that won't yet issue the query (or queries) until you start actually using the albums in your code. For example. `a.albums.first.name`. Again, lazy loading at work.

Comment: i've tried what you said but i'm stumbling with an error which says that:
NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for "Album":String

Comment: @lagranzotto Please show what you've tried in your original problem statement to make that clear, and then folks here can help you more effectively. Show exactly what you tried and the precise error messages you saw in each case.